# Adding a +More Colors label to collection page of WP theme – f(x)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, function

I'm using the the Advanced Woo Labels plug-in on Wordpress to create frontend labels for products given certain rule sets. I've added this snippet to my functions.php file, but i need to adjust the logic so that the ruleset matches my conditions. Problem is... i don't know how to write the logic

Instead of the snippet below which adds a *special label for variable products if at least one of its child products quantity equal/not equal/less/greater than X*. I need to add a special label if a product has more than 1 attributes = color.

EX: product https://thewalnuttreeaurora.com/product/line-dress/ has 2 color variants.

I know this logic is incorrect for my scenario, that's why i need assistance in updating it to check IF product has multiple attributes of color (EX: gray, white)

```
add_filter( 'awl_label_rules', 'my_awl_label_rules' );
function my_awl_label_rules( $options ) {
 
    $options['Custom'][] = array(
        "name" => __( "Variable product with child quantity", "advanced-woo-labels" ),
        "id"   => "custom_var_quantity",
        "type" => "number",
        "operators" => "equals_compare",
    );
 
    return $options;
 
}
 
add_filter( 'awl_labels_condition_rules', 'my_awl_labels_condition_rules' );
function my_awl_labels_condition_rules( $rules ) {
    $rules['custom_var_quantity'] = 'condition_custom_var_quantity';
    return $rules;
}
 
function condition_custom_var_quantity( $condition_rule ) {
 
    global $product;
 
    $match = false;
 
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        if ( sizeof( $product->get_children() ) > 0 ) {
 
            foreach ($product->get_children() as $child_id) {
 
                $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation($child_id);
                $variation_quantity = $variation_product->get_stock_quantity();
 
                $match = awl_compare_condition_values( $condition_rule['operator'], $variation_quantity, $condition_rule['value'] );
 
                if ( $match ) {
                    break;
                }
 
            }
        }
    }
 
    return $match;
 
}
```